# Google Cloud SDK gcloud error

Tags: windows-7-x64, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I use Google Cloud SDK under Window 7 64bit.
Google Cloud SDK and python install success. and run gcloud.

The error occurs as shown below.

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 137, in <
module>
    _cli = CreateCLI()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 98, in Cr
eateCLI
sdk_root = config.Paths().sdk_root
AttributeError: 'Paths' object has no attribute 'sdk_root'
```

Can ask for help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. And this helped me solve this problem

Manually removed directory: C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK

Then rerun: GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe

And make sure that you have connection to needed DL servers (I was first behind company firewall and installer didn't download all files - and no complains either by installer...)

Then I was OK again..

Source: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=62&thanks=62&ts=1407851956

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk

gcloud init
```