# google cloud sdk: set environment variable_ python --> linux

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, gcloud

```
ERROR: Python 3 is not supported by the Google Cloud SDK.  Please use a Python 2.x version that is 2.6 or greater.

If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.
```

I guess the first question we should be asking is *"with all the money google makes off of their customers why can't they hire someone to ensure that their cloud sdk works with python 3?"*

How exactly to overcome this error on linux? What specific files need to be edited? and where should those files be located?

I searched around, a lot, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449779/google-cloud-sdk-gcloud-error) about how to fix this on Windows, but the answer is not really that comprehensive.

---

**Thus far I've attempted:**

One source of documentationsays to modify a file called `app.yaml`, but I searched using the command `find . -name "app.yaml"` and no such file exists.

Specifically I'm using arch linux, I originally tried to use the [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-cloud-sdk/) but it's disfunctional.

So I installed from the [documentation](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?projectId=symmetric-hash-97616), making sure to edit the `./install.sh` file, specifying `python2` as per this discussion on [the google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sdk/I0o6aSrLlao), that doesn't work either. after running the command `gcloud auth login` I get the same error as posted above.

Comment: Why can you not do exactly what the message says, and set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable? Why do you think files need to be "edited"?

Comment: so what is that? just `set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = *location of python2`?

Comment: Yes, something like this:

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/path/to/appropriate/python`

Comment: What does that do exactly? Changes my ~/bashrc file is it?

Comment: `I guess the first question we should be asking is "with all the money google makes off of their customers why can't they hire someone to ensure that their cloud sdk works with python 3?"` -same here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very easy thing to solve. The native *python* command on the Arch command line is actually for Python 3. The SDK requires Python2.7 and the

- Just go to the google-cloud-sdk folder and open the *install.sh* file.
- Change the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="python" value to CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="python2.7"
- Rerun the install with the command

  ```
  ./install.sh
  ```

  in the same folder and follow the prompts.

That's all.

Comment: Thats what that Google group said to do, I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Maybe I need to say "2.7", I said 2 only

Comment: Specify it - python2.7

Comment: By the way, use this command <pre>export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2.7</pre> after installation to avoid any potential post installation problem.

Comment: that changes my file `~/bashrc` isn't it? is that what that command does?

Comment: Only for that terminal session. I found that after installation, anytime I tried to use the gcloud commands led to an error but setting the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to python2.7 worked as a temporary fix for the session.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue so I did a little change in the `dev_appserver.py`. This file is in the following path :

```
google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

**change the shebang** from `/usr/bin/env python` to  `/usr/bin/env python2`

Comment: `whereis dev_appserver.py`

Answer (score 0):

I see this almost every time I update gcloud SDK, especially when running `dev_appserver.py <my app config yaml file>`

I found that setting the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON env variable to 'python2' seems to silence the error. E.g on macOS:

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2`

Not sure why they simply cannot make this dev server compatible with Python 3 already

Comment: `gcloud` is now compatible with python3

Comment: The problem now is that I get an error about a python3 version in CLOUDSDK_PYTHON.