# Python Error on Google Cloud Install. How do I properly set the environment variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, path, gcloud

I am trying to install the Google Cloud SDK on my **Windows** machine. I have Python 2.7 currently installed on this machine, and it's located in the System Variables Path like this -> `C:\Python27\;`

I am getting this error during installation:

> ERROR: gcloud failed to load: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.

The error message also prompts me to check the Python executable by saying:

> If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to
>   point to a working Python 2.7 executable.

So, I'm trying to set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable in the install.sh shell script...But nothing is working. Here is the code from that file:

```
echo Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

if [ -z "$CLOUDSDK_PYTHON" ]; then
 if [ -z "$(which python)" ]; then
  echo
  echo "To use the Google Cloud SDK, you must have Python installed and on your PATH."
  echo "As an alternative, you may also set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable"
  echo "to the location of your Python executable."
  exit 1
 fi
 CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="python"
fi
```

**I have tried** `python2.7`, and the path to the executable, `C:\Python27`, but I'm getting this error when I try to run the script with those variables:

```
install.sh: line 128: $'python\r': command not found
```

I found this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832990/google-cloud-sdk-set-environment-variable-python-linux), but none of the solutions worked for me. Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the env var is expected to point to the actual python executable (i.e. the actual `C:\Python27\python.exe` file - or whatever its name is - can't really check as I'm not using windows), not just the directory where the executable is located?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yeah, I just checked that as well. Still received the same error message. -> "install.sh: line 128: $'C:\\Python27\\python.exe\r': command not found".

Comment: How are you setting the env var? I'd just run `SET CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe` in the terminal where the installation script will later be executed.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue when the **sdk** was pointing to the *virtualenv python*. I solved it by using the default python2.7 in **Ubuntu**

Type this in termimal

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because the `gcloud.bat` command can't find the right python.exe. I solved the problem by simply put

```
SET CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=pathWherePythonexeLocate
```

into the file `cloud_env.bat` in google Cloud SDK file folder.
And revise the `install.sh` won't help, because it do nothing to the `env` since the `install.sh` was run when you first install gcloud sdk.
and sdk only support python2.7, so the path is pointed to python2.7, such as `C:\myname\soft\python27.exe`

Answer (score 4):

Two configurations fixed my issue with this.

1. My laptop runs Windows 10, and I found that there was file:

```
C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

That file is size 0 Kb. This directory was ahead of the C:\Python27 path where Python was actually installed. I tried moving C:\Python27 higher in the Path string, but this did not work.

While I did not reboot, I did open a fresh CMD window and confirmed that C:\Python27 was higher in the path than the AppData directory. Still did not work.

2. When I changed the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON path, just the "path" is not enough. The FULL path must be provided, *including* the executable name.

Making these two changes enabled gCloud to work.

*Of course* just as I finished typing the above, I saw email from Google regarding the change below.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** Python 2.7 will no longer get updates after Jan 1, 2020, so gcloud as of v274.0.0 will run with Python 3x. I can't find a web page announcing this, but there is mention of the change on this page: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this was simply by downloading the Versioned SDK instead of the Interactive SDK. I manually added gcloud to my path, and all worked. I still don't know why the interactive download was not finding Python from my systems path, but the Versioned SDK without Python worked.

Thanks for the tips @DanCornilescu.

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing the issue on 274.0.0 on Windows,

This is being tracked in the public bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146458519

An [employee replied](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146458519#comment10):

> We have a patch for two files that are causing these problems.  These
>   apply in two cases (both on Windows):
>   1.  A new install fails, or
>   2.  You are unable to run gcloud after performing a components update.
>
> For case # 1, please download the attached file  install.bat, and copy
>   it to the location where you have attempted to install gcloud, e.g.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.  Then run
>   it, e.g.
>
> ```
> > cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk
> > .\install.bat
> ```
>
> For both cases #1 and #2, download the attached file gcloud.cmd, and
>   copy it to the bin directory under your gcloud installation, e.g.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin.  When
>   prompted to replace the previous copy, type Yes.  This should allow
>   you to run gcloud without being prompted to set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON.

The files are attached in the public bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Add `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` in your system variable and assign it the value of your python.exe file as shown below :
[image]

*Restart your services so that the change can take effect.*