# GCloud powershell commands throw error but works fine in cmd

Tags: powershell, windows-10, gcloud

When I run GCloud comannds via windows cmd prompt it works.

But when I run them via powershell it throws an error in red, but the command gets completed successfully.

Eg:

**1) Auth**

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account xxx@xxx-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=C:\xxxxx\cred.json
```

**Error:**

```
python.exe : Activated service account credentials for: [xxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
At xxxxxxxxxxxx\gcloud.ps1:117 char:3
+   & "$cloudsdk_python" $run_args_array
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Activated servi...iceaccount.com]:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

**2) Upload file to storage bucket**

```
gsutil cp $outputFile gs://bucketxxx
```

**Error:**

```
gsutil : Copying file://N:\out\sqlserver\tag.csv [Content-Type=application/vnd.ms-excel]...
At xxxxxxx\RDS_SQLServer_ExportData_DataWarehouse.ps1:38 char:5
+     gsutil cp $outputFile gs://bucketxxx  | out-null
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Copying file://...nd.ms-excel]...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/  2.8 MiB]                                                
/ [1 files][  2.8 MiB/  2.8 MiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/2.8 MiB.
```

---

Comment: I am also getting same error

Comment: I found one solution as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722209/5591519

Answer (score 1):

I was not able comment, hence adding my inputs here.

First : The issue only seems to occur when this is run via Powershell ISE and not when executed via powershell prompt.

Second : This is not as such an error, for example when you see your own error you find the text after Not Specified as "Activated servi..."  which means the action is sucessfully performed. Hope this helps to someone else stumbeling over here

```
python.exe : Activated service account credentials for: [xxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
At xxxxxxxxxxxx\gcloud.ps1:117 char:3
+   & "$cloudsdk_python" $run_args_array
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Activated servi...iceaccount.com]:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```