# How to set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON for Google Cloud in Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, centos6, google-cloud-sdk

if I run:

```
sudo gcloud components update
```

I get this warning:

> WARNING:  Python 3.4.x is no longer officially supported by the Google
> Cloud SDK and may not function correctly.  Please use Python version
> 2.7.x or 3.5 and up.
>
> If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it
> by setting the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.

My linux machine is Centos6 and my current python default versions are these:

```
myshell$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
myshell$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.10
```

I installed a Python 3.6 version, which is located here:

> /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python

```
myshell$ /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python --version
Python 3.6.9
```

I hence added this line to the .bash_profile and sourced it:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python
```

but I still get the same warning when running gcloud commands

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

For me following statement worked

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.8
```

I set 3.8 as for me error was "**Pleases use Python version 3.5 or up**"

Answer (score 4):

I think you can solve it do it the described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832990/google-cloud-sdk-set-environment-variable-python-linux).

*Just go to the google-cloud-sdk folder and open the install.sh file.

*Change the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="python" value to CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="python2.7"

*Rerun the install with the command

```
./install.sh
```